# Inserting to after a given node in a Linked List

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I'm having trouble debugging the following error. I have a linked list and I'm trying to insert a value into the position somewhere between the head and tail. But I'm having trouble calling the `new_node` value from the `Node` class. Does this have to do with the version of python I'm using?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linked_list_add_after_given_node.py", line 47, in <module>
    a.insert_after(2,42)
  File "linked_list_add_after_given_node.py", line 34, in insert_after
    new_node.next_node = prev_node.next_node
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next_node'
```

This is what my linked list looks like:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None, next_node=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next_node = next_node

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size
    
    def push(self, new_value):
        # 1 & 2: Init a node
        #        insert data into node
        new_node = Node(new_value)
        # 3. make next of new node the head
        new_node.next_node = self.head
        # 4. Mode head to point to new node
        self.head = new_node
        self.size += 1

    def insert_after(self, prev_node, new_value):
        # 1. check if prev_node exists
        if prev_node is None:
            print("The given previous node must be in Linked List.")
            return 
        # 2. Create new node
        # 3. insert value
        new_node = Node(new_value)

        # 4. Make next of new Node as next of previous node
        new_node.next_node = prev_node.next_node

        # 5. make next of prev_node as new node
        prev_node.next_node = new_node

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = LinkedList()
    a.push(1)
    a.push(2)
    a.push(100)
    a.push(1000)
    a.insert_after(2,42)
    print(a.__len__())
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `LinkedList.insert_after()` with `prev_node=2` (an 'int' object) but it expects `prev_node` has an attribute `'next_node'`, such as a `Node` object.

You'll need to either find the node you want to insert after and send it as `prev_node` when you call `insert_after`, or you could modify `insert_after` to take an `int` and then find the first node in the linked list with that value.

I would do this by adding a `__iter__` to `LinkedList`, renaming `insert_after` parameter `prev_node` to `prev_value`, then adding a for loop at the top of `insert_after` to find the node to insert after and assign it to `prev_node`.

```
Class LinkedList:

    ...

    def __iter__(self):
        curr = self.head
        while curr:
            yield curr
            curr = curr.next_node

    def insert_after(self, prev_value, new_value):
        prev_node = None
        for node in self:
            if node.value == prev_value:
                prev_node = node
                break

        # 1. check if prev_node exists
        ....
```